# Prevent downloads in Safari and instead open them directly in the browser

Tags: macos, safari, pdf

In the web, there is often a link to a file, like a pdf document.
If clicked on it, Safari (on the Mac) downloads the file. 
I want to prevent this and instead open the file directly in Safari (as Safari certainly is capable of doing that).
So the behaviour I want to achieve is the same as Safari on the iPhone where files are not downloaded but opened always directly in the browser.

Note: This is not about setting Safari to ask before downloading which can be done in the Settings but instead telling it to open the specific document directly from the internet.

Comment: You have PDF tagged.  Is this only for PDFs or for all files?

Comment: When I open a pdf file in Safari it shows the file. i have to option-click on the link to download it. im running High-Sierra on an old iMac. And my Safari is version 13.1

Comment: It's for all files but it happens mainly with PDFs. @jmh: Yes, for most files this behaviour is the case, but sometimes the files are downloaded (e.g. if the link on the website says "download file"). I don't want this and instead open it in the browser.